# Filling a Triangle Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, graphics, 2d

I am currently trying to complete an algorithm that fills a drawn triangle. The way I have been doing it is by iterating through the shape and drawing single lines. I have an almost-perfect algorithm, except for a small issue. When I have a horizontal side, the filling fails.

Here is my current filling algorithm. I should notes that the multidimensional arrays called origin, coor2, and coor3 are represented as the vertices of my triangle (origin[0][0] = x of origin, origin[ 0][1 ]= y of origin). Coordinates are typical window with (0,0) being in the upper left. Also, the gc is simply what I need to draw in a window.

```
void triangle::drawFilled(GraphicsContext* gc)
{
// color
gc->setColor(colorRGB);
// algorithm variables
double ax = origin[0][0];
double bx = coor2[0][0];
double cx = coor3[0][0];
double ay = origin[1][0];
double by = coor2[1][0];
double cy = coor3[1][0];

// sort vertices by y
if (ay > by)
{
    std::swap(ay, by);
    std::swap(ax, bx);
}
if (ay > cy)
{
    std::swap(ay, cy);
    std::swap(ax, cx);
}
if (by > cy)
{
    std::swap(by, cy);
    std::swap(bx, cx);
}

// define more algorithm variables
double dx1 = (cx-ax)/(cy-ay);
double dx2 = (bx-ax)/(by-ay);
double dx3 = (cx-bx)/(cy-by);
double x1 = ax;
double x2 = ax;

// loop through coordinates
for(int y = ay; y < by; y++)
{
    gc->drawLine(x1,y,x2,y);
    x1 += dx1;
    x2 += dx2;
}

// loop through coordinates
for(int y = by; y < cy; y++)
{
    gc->drawLine(x1,y,x2,y);
    x1 += dx1;
    x2 += dx3;
}
}
```

[Here's an example of my results when there are not horizontal sides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEGb6.png)

[And here's when there is a horizontal side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itDAF.png)

Note how the outline and the fill are not lining up.

I realize that the problem likely lies in the sorting of the y vertices and thus doesn't account for x. I could just brute force my method to handle all situations of horizontal and vertical edges, but that seems quite inefficient. I would rather learn how to solve my dilemma than try to work around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code depends on the side effect of the first loop setting `x2` to `bx`.  When `dx2` is infinity that wouldn't work anyway and doesn't even try.

So right after that first loop, just set `x2=bx;`

Most of the time that extra step is redundant, but it is trivial and when the top side is horizontal, it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

i'm sure you no longer need this, but your issue is relatively simple. for the condition that the top of the triangle is flat and the bottom is flat you need conditional statements

```
if(TopIsFlat){

}else if(BottomIsFlat){

}else{
    pre existing code
}
```

for the top and bottom you will have to figure out what x coordinate you will be starting with. and swap if necessary if you swap you will have to switch the slopes as well.

also print the slopes between points to make sure your slopes are correct;

example using Struct

```
struct Vector2D{
    int x, y,
}
struct Triangle{
   Vector2D p[3];
}

void Fill(Triangle ySwap){
    
    if(ySwap.p[0].y > ySwap.p[1].y) std::swap(ySwap.p[0], ySwap.p[1]);
    if(ySwap.p[1].y > ySwap.p[2].y) std::swap(ySwap.p[1], ySwap.p[2]);
    if(ySwap.p[0].y > ySwap.p[1].y) std::swap(ySwap.p[0], ySwap.p[1]);
    
    float slope1 = ((float)(ySwap.p[1].x-ySwap.p[0].x)/(ySwap.p[1].y-ySwap.p[0].y));
    float slope2 = ((float)(ySwap.p[2].x-ySwap.p[1].x)/(ySwap.p[2].y-ySwap.p[1].y));
    float slope3 = ((float)(ySwap.p[2].x-ySwap.p[0].x)/(ySwap.p[2].y-ySwap.p[0].y));
    
    float x1; float x2;
    if(ySwap.p[0].y == ySwap.p[1].y){
        
        if(ySwap.p[1].x > ySwap.p[0].x){
            x1 = ySwap.p[0].x;
            x2 = ySwap.p[1].x;
        }else{
            x1 = ySwap.p[1].x;
            x2 = ySwap.p[0].x;
            std::swap(slope2, slope3);
        }
        for(int y = ySwap.p[0].y; y < ySwap.p[2].y; y++){
            DrawLine(x1, y, x2, y, 'T');
            x1 += slope3;
            x2 += slope2;
        }
        
    }else if(ySwap.p[1].y == ySwap.p[2].y){
        
        if(ySwap.p[2].x > ySwap.p[1].x){
            x1 = ySwap.p[0].x;
            x2 = ySwap.p[2].x;
        }else{
            x1 = ySwap.p[2].x;
            x2 = ySwap.p[0].x;
            std::swap(slope1, slope3);
        }
        for(int y = ySwap.p[0].y; y < ySwap.p[2].y; y++){
            DrawLine(x1, y, x2, y, 'B');
            x1 += slope3;
            x2 += slope1;
        }
        
    }else{
        
        x1 = ySwap.p[0].x;
        x2 = ySwap.p[0].x;
        
        for(int y = ySwap.p[0].y ; y < ySwap.p[1].y; y++){
            DrawLine(x1, y, x2, y, '+');
            x1 += slope3;
            x2 += slope1;
        }
        
        for(int y = ySwap.p[1].y; y < ySwap.p[2].y; y++){
            DrawLine(x1, y, x2, y, '-');
            x1 += slope3;
            x2 += slope2;
        }
    }
    
    screen[ySwap.p[0].x][ySwap.p[0].y] = '*';
    screen[ySwap.p[1].x][ySwap.p[1].y] = '*';
    screen[ySwap.p[2].x][ySwap.p[2].y] = '*';
    
    DrawTriangle(ySwap.p[0].x, ySwap.p[0].y, ySwap.p[1].x, ySwap.p[1].y, ySwap.p[2].x, ySwap.p[2].y, '*');
}
```

your code actually allowed me to finish my triangle draw function which had some errors this should work better also this code will allow you to see each corner edge and different triangle split although you will have to hook it up to your own line draw function along with a char array that is printed.